# How to pass FromDate and ToDate to crystal report programmatically in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I generated one summary report in my application. I am working with mvc4. I generated that report using Crystal report. Now I have one view. In that view I have two fields called `FromDate`, `ToDate`. If I select `FromDate` and `ToDate` and click the ok button it will generate the report as per that two dates criteria and display the report.

My Report

[image: my report]

Now that is working well. What I want is to keep `FromDate` and `Todate` in the place which I marked in the report below. How do I do that? How do I pass the dates to crystal report? Any help to resolve this issue?

My Controller code

```
public ActionResult GetOrderComplaintsValues(VisitorsViewModel vvm)
{
    var ObjFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(vvm.FromDate);
    var ObjTodate = Convert.ToDateTime(vvm.ToDate);
    var objpovisitID =  vvm.POVisitID;

    var objText = "Order";
    if(objpovisitID == new Guid("DB7FE0EA-8444-4F6B-9961-4F54E7C4F0FD"))
    {
        var PurchaseOrderCount = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm where v.POVisitID == objpovisitID && v.VisitingDate >= ObjFromDate && v.VisitingDate <= ObjTodate select v).ToList();
    }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.0.73\SQLEXPRESS,14330;Initial Catalog=WafeERP_NEW;User ID=sa;Password=wafewin;");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        if (objpovisitID == new Guid("DB7FE0EA-8444-4F6B-9961-4F54E7C4F0FD"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from View_VisitorsForm where POVisitID= '" + objpovisitID + "' and VisitingDate >='" + ObjFromDate + "'and VisitingDate <= '" + ObjTodate + "'", con);
             SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        }
        else if (objpovisitID == new Guid("283462E7-665D-44D1-A469-B8AF2D913B8B"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from View_VisitorsForm where POVisitID= '" + objpovisitID + "' and VisitingDate >='" + ObjFromDate + "'and VisitingDate <= '" + ObjTodate + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
        }
         else if (objpovisitID == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from View_VisitorsForm where  VisitingDate >='" + ObjFromDate + "'and VisitingDate <= '" + ObjTodate + "'", con);
              SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    ReportClass rc = new ReportClass();
    rc.FileName = Server.MapPath("/Reports/rpt_OrderComplaintsSummaryReport.rpt");
    rc.Load();
    rc.SetDataSource(dt);
    Stream stream = rc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```